APEX "Interactive Grid" - how to show system date in UI footer for every page?
APEX version: 22.2.
I've an APEX app with an "Interactive Grid" (IG).  The applicable page has a hidden "P1_SYSDATE" item set to the current date. Within the IG's "Region" tab's "Footer Text", I know I can specify "&P1_SYSDATE." but the footer only renders after the very last page. Does anyone know of a way to have the IG footer render on every page?  (preferably within the same line as the IG's built-in page # footer, as it does with the "Printing" tab footer for an IG's downloaded PDF)

